# Setting A Callback Function To A Timer

Tags: javascript, ajax, timer

I'm so close to finishing this program and I can't figure out this last piece. I have my webpage reaching out to a server to grab a randomly generated number, which it then plots onto a graph. I need to set it so it plots the data points every 2 seconds and I can't figure out how to set up my `setInterval` command. I can get it to work with a `for` loop, but this obviously isn't timed. It also crashes when I set the limit past a certain threshold, which may indicate a problem when trying to use the timer. I'll post my code along with some of the things I've tried.

Code first:

```
function plotData(dataSet) 
{
var x = xScale+20; // 20 = margin length
var y = 260;    //origin of graph

context.strokeStyle="#0000FF";
context.beginPath();

for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
  getRequest(function(random)
  { 
    var diff = (dataSet[0]*100) - (dataSet[1] * 100);
    diff = diff/5;                                                          
    y = y+(diff*23);

    context.lineTo(x, y);
    context.moveTo(x, y);
    context.stroke();   

    x=x+xScale;
    console.log("dataSet = "+dataSet[0]+", "+dataSet[1]);
    dataSet[0] = dataSet[1];
  });   
}
}
```

I have it set to a loop for debugging purposes right now.

The callback function reaches to an `XMLHttpRequest` to grab the random number (I can post this code too if needed).

What I was trying to do was implement `setInterval` along with some booleans to stop the function upon a second function call.

Something like this:

```
var isRunning = false;

function plotData(dataSet) 
{
 if (isRunning == false)
 {
  isRunning = true;
 }

 if (isRunning == true)
 {
  isRunning = false;
  myTimer = clearInterval();
 }
var myTimer;
var x = xScale+20; // 20 = margin length
var y = 260;    //origin of graph

context.strokeStyle="#0000FF";
context.beginPath();

 while (isRunning == true)
 {
  myTimer = setInterval(function()
  { 
   getRequest(function(random)
   {    
    var diff = (dataSet[0]*100) - (dataSet[1] * 100);
    diff = diff/5;                                                          
    y = y+(diff*23);

    context.lineTo(x, y);
    context.moveTo(x, y);
    context.stroke();   

    x=x+xScale;
    console.log("dataSet = "+dataSet[0]+", "+dataSet[1]);
    dataSet[0] = dataSet[1];
   });
  }, 2000);

 }
}
```

I added a global boolean `isRunning` for handling purposes.

I set `isRunning` to true if it was previously false (indicating that it is now in progress).

I set `isRunning` to false if it was previously true then proceed to `clearInterval` to stop it.

And lastly set up a `while` loop for the callback function to execute while `isRunning == true`

All this did was crash my program. How can I use the `setInterval` function correctly in this case?

Comment: `while (isRunning == true)
 {
  myTimer = setInterval(function()` you're adding a new interval every iteration of your loop ... and this code would lock up most browsers

Comment: Good catch. Is this the correct syntax to implant code into the `setInterval` function?

Comment: Just checked it, this is the correct syntax. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a setInterval, use can use setTimeout.

There will be one function that calls the XMLHttpRequest and handles the response. Call this function in a [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) from the response callback in the XMLHttpRequest. This will mean that the next request will always be 2 seconds after the last response (and the last plot). This will avoid using the flags to check if there is a request in progress.

```
function plotData(dataSet) {
  var x = xScale+20; // 20 = margin length
  var y = 260;    //origin of graph

  context.strokeStyle="#0000FF";
  context.beginPath();

  var counter = 10;

  function plotPoint() {
    getRequest(function(data) {
      var diff = (dataSet[0]*100) - (dataSet[1] * 100);
      diff = diff/5;
      y = y+(diff*23);

      context.lineTo(x, y);
      context.moveTo(x, y);
      context.stroke();   

      x = x + xScale;
      console.log("dataSet = "+dataSet[0]+", "+dataSet[1]);
      dataSet[0] = dataSet[1];

      if (counter-- > 0) {
        setTimeout(plotPoint, 2000);
      }
    }
  }

  plotPoint();
}
```

Comment: setTimeout wont fix the fact that once the condition in the while loop is true, it will always be true, and lock up the browser

Comment: There won't be a while loop or the flags in this case. Sending the request is async, so all the request are basically sent in the same time. The best way would be to send the next request only after the first one is complete.

Comment: sorry, thought you were saying that the only change required was `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` - my bad

Comment: Is the number of times a timer is to be set known beforehand? Didn't he say that the for loop using 10 iterations was just for debugging purposes? I might have misunderstood the question, in which case your answer is what needs to be done.

Comment: I might have misunderstood that. I believe there needs to be a stopping condition anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the check `isRunning == true` inside the callback passed to setInterval(). Try something like this,

```js
myTimer = setInterval(function(){
  if(isRunning == true) {
    /* clear the timer */
  }
  /* Else perform the request */
}, 2000)
```

When `isRunning` evaluates to true, the timer will be cleared stopping subsequent `setInterval`.